# Another Cannot modify header information headers already sent by... script.php... pluggable.php issue

Tags: wordpress

This is the code I have. It is my scripts.php include file. And this is the error I get when attempting to go to my admin panel for the WordPress site.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xar19/public_html/backlinks5/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/scripts.php:12) in /home/xar19/public_html/backlinks5/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866

I have checked all the other inc. files and they do not have ?> either as I found out it is not a requirement. However at one point they had a closing ?> and I still got the exact same error. I have attempted to move the button script
above all of the other script src files but I still run into errors.

Could it be because they are anonymous functions? The plugin works I just can no longer access my admin.

I do not get any errors when I use localhost and have my plugin files loaded there. However I assume that is simply because it has the latest version of php. Also I have disabled all other plugins for debugging purposes.

I have been trying for days to get this resolved and have lost a lot of sleep over something I think is probably a basic issue.

Thanks so much,

Danielle

```
<?php 
/****************************************
*script control
****************************************/

function brb_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('brb-styles', plugin_dir_url( __file__ ) . 'css/plugin_styles.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'brb_load_scripts');

<script src="wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>

<script src="wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/slider.js"></script>

<script>

 (function() {

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
      $(".wrap").slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass("button"); return false;
    });


  });

})(); 
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get to wp-admin by setting up a new php file and added everything after

"`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'brb_load_scripts');`"

Which left me with 2 files now one that loads the  CSS/styles and one that contains my JQuery script.

SO now I only run into my header error when I change themes or change the settings I have set up for my plugin. This will still change the theme and setting but the error shows up and I am required to reload my main page to see the changes.

I should mention I am also still getting this error on activation.

"`The plugin generated 596 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.`"

and actually I changed the scripts from      "`<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>`"

back to     "`<script src="wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>`"

because either still gives me the errors but the first suggested below causes 630 characters of unexpected output instead of just 596.

Comment: Check for any error messages in firebug or chrome inspect element.

Comment: The only error I get when I check those are that it says that the script resources are not loaded. However again on the main page they do load just not when I attempt to access site/wp-admin/

Thank you for your response though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  `<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>` in front of your script's link.

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>

<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/js/slider.js"></script>
```

This will loads the script correctly. Check it.

Comment: I tried entering what you have posted here instead of what I had but I still run into the same error. I also realized that I missed adding ?> on this page after this line "add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'brb_load_scripts');" If I do not add ?> after that line I get a syntax error instead ~ 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/xar19/public_html/backlinks5/wp-content/plugins/bounce_rate_buddy3/includes/scripts.php on line 12
  ~  
It seems my code really does not like line 12 lol.